# Design View not working on Visual Studio 2019 in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I started a new project with ASP.NET layout.

The code is ok, but when I try to see the designer view, VS freezes and doesn't show it.

I've tried repair, reinstall, `devenv.exe /SkipPkgs`... but still nothing...

Sometimes when I type <kbd>Shift + F7</kbd>, I get an error "class not registered", but not every time.

Does someone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found to solve this was by installing Windows again =/

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio Installer - I just modified/upgraded to VS community 2022, version 17.4.0 ... fixed the problem.